# <identifier> expected when creating an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing an airline program that will allow the user to input names and meal choice for each seating section economy, business, and first. I am trying to save all the names and meals into an array. but I am getting a syntax error.

I get  expected message when I implement my flyer array.

I have looked on stack overflow. From what I can tell it should be ok to initialize my array this way.

Thanks for any help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Flyers 
{    
    public Flyers()
    {

    }

    public List<String> seat = new ArrayList<>();
    int numberOfFlyers;
    int numberOfMeals;
    String name;
    String meal;    

    String[][] flyer;

    public void addEconomyFlyer()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of economy seats sold: ");
        numberOfFlyers = in.nextInt();

        flyer = new [numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers];
    }  
}
```

Comment: What do you think `new [numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers]` does and why do you think so?

Comment: Why are you making `flyer` a two-dimensional array?  It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: `I have looked on stack overflow. From what I can tell it should be ok to initialize my array this way` Please link a question/answer you saw that showed your initialization as ok.

Comment: I want each [][] to have the same number of items that is equal to the number of people on the plane. Then I will add a nested for loop that will add a name for each of the flyers, and a meal choice. ultimately i need to  be able to print out the array Name and their Meal choice.

Comment: OK, I think you've misunderstood what a two-dimensional array does.  Suppose there are 300 people on the plane.  `new String[numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers]` will create 90000 Strings.  Do you think you might be better off with two one-dimensional arrays?  One for the names and one for the meal choices?

Comment: David thanks. I did know that at one point, but I guess I got confused. And I thought about doing two separate arrays, but then I wasn't sure how to match each meal to the name and I thought this might be a better option.

Comment: OK, so you could have two arrays then, say `flyerNames` and `mealTypes` - and you'd create them with `flyerNames = new String[numberOfFlyers];` and `mealTypes = new String[numberOfFlyers];`.  Is that enough information to get you started?  Alternatively, just copy Elliott's answer - it's different from this, but it works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want each [][] to have the same number of items that is equal to the number of people on the plane. Then I will add a nested for loop that will add a name for each of the flyers, and a meal choice. ultimately i need to be able to print out the array Name and their Meal choice.

Almost, the issue here is you haven't specified a type for the array.

```
flyer = new [numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers];
```

should probably be

```
flyer = new String[numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers];
```

However that doesn't make a lot sense. One solution is to use,

```
flyer = new String[numberOfFlyers][2];
```

where 0 is name and 1 is meal. But, really you should probably have a flyer POJO,

```
flyer = new Flyer[numberOfFlyers];
```

Where `Flyer` might look something like,

```
class Flyer {
  Flyer(String name, String mealType) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mealType = mealType;
  }
  String name;
  String mealType;
  public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + ", Meal: " + mealType;
  }
}
```

Then you can create new Flyer(s) and call `toString()` in your loop. You might also choose to add getter and setter functions for `name` and `mealType`.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
flyer = new [numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers];
```

to:

```
flyer = new String[numberOfFlyers][numberOfFlyers];
```

Comment: When creating any array in Java, you need to provide the data type as well with `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner class

```
 Scan.scanner.scan
```

You need scan it!!!!

```
identifier = here
```

This trickes computer in think identifier there! YES! WORK!